# Maven copy dependencies working correct in windows but not in linux

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have spring boot project which uses thin jar plugin to copy dependencies. I am copying all the dependencies in one folder. I was not getting any class not found error before as jars were present in respective folder. It was working both in windows and linux. I updated spring boot version to 2.7.5. While building in windows all jars are present in form of thin jars. No error. But while building in linux jar from repository is not getting copy to respective folder. for e.g spring-context-support jar is missing in /org/springframework/spring-context-support/5.3.24/ location.
In maven repository this jars is present. But in linux while copying to common folder only pom is getting copied. So I am getting class not found error.
But in windows its working correctly.

I cross check setting.xml. But still not able to point what is happening.

Comment: Check what is actually being downloaded.  Do you use \ as the directory separator character?

Comment: Can you show the pom file which is doing the copying?

Comment: Separator is there it was working before. If I downgrade the version it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, except that we are not using Spring Boot. On Windows, the dependencies are copied from our maven repository just fine, but on a Linux runner, nothing (and no error during maven build).

I solved this problem the following way:

In my parent pom, where my dependencies were declared and where copy-dependecies is invoked, I had them declared only into the <dependencyManagement /> section.
I declared them also outside in the <dependencies /> section (just referencing the groupId and the artifactId like in the children), and it worked!